# semi-dashed arrow

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

Is it possible to draw a symbol looking like `\DashedRightarrow` in this:

[image]

I would need such a symbol in a `\xymatrix` environment. If it is not possible without modifying heavily XYpics, then I will use something else of course.

Comment: please give us some MWE to work with. Thanks.

Comment: And give picture of what you want...

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. This will help us help you ! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Is this what you're after: http://i.imgur.com/N8mEhzz.png ?

Comment: @alwaysask  yes exactly ! In what package is it please ? You could put that as an answer.

Comment: @alwaysask And is it possible to put that kind of arrow in xypics ? I browsed the user's manual and I did not see this symbol.

Comment: No package, it's just a drawing. Please put it in your question, add any details about what you want to use it for and someone will give you an answer shortly. I have to go out for 3-4 hours.

Comment: Please include an MWE (as ebo said above) with a `\xymatrix` example. Use normal double lines in the diagram and tell us where in the compiled result you want  a mixed dashed/cont double arrow. I don't think you can use symbols for arrows in `xymatrix`.

Comment: @alwaysask OK, It is what I wanted to know and why I asked the question. I will use another symbol.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher Please post your image in your question. I cannot open external links here. Have you seen examples with `tikz-cd` which use symbols as arrows? Works great there. As you have not provided an MWE yet, I tend to close your question as unclear. Please let us know, if there is still interest in this topic. Thank you.